# Backbone transitions between views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

In my rails app with backbone.js on client side, I have diffirent views for each of my page and when I navigate through my pages, I get a standart transitions(first page disappear,second appear). But I need to create some visual effects between views transitions, something like [usatoday](http://www.usatoday.com/) or [goldmansachs](http://www.goldmansachs.com/)
Does anybody know how to do this ?

Comment: A view logically should not handle its transition. Router, on the other hand...

Comment: My router already do this, but I also have some events(click link/btn) in my views, which navigate to other pages.

Comment: If your browser has to load another page, you can't really do anything with it. At best you can transition out (use [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)), load the page, and then transition in. But if you need such degree of control, you should probably consider using one-page app using either Backbone.js or CompoundJS. If you want to use rails, you can try using [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), which is available for Rails 3 and will be used in Rails 4 by default.

Comment: I have already use backbone, I mentioned about it in my question. I only need to create such visual effect like in links I've posted.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: I understood you. But this isn't what i need. I created my app using single-page-app style, and when I said navigate through pages, I ment  that I load templates from each views, I can several views on one page or only one and it will load all data on one page. And my question is how to realize such effectc from links when I load data between two views

Comment: So what's preventing you from doing transitions in the router?

Comment: Like I said, if you have to leave the browser page, your only choice is beforeunload.

Answer (score 1):

You might find Backbone.ViewKit (https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.viewkit) useful.  It manages the navigation and transitions between views.  There are a couple transitions built-in (slide and fade) but you can write your own transitions as well.